# Generate dynamic routes in Nuxt.js from front matter in markdown files from other content directories

Tags: markdown, nuxt.js, dynamically-generated

I have markdown files in the following folder structures:

```
content
-- blog
-- guest
-- random
```

Each markdown file has a front matter `tags` array. I would like to create a `/tags/_id.vue` dynamic path for each tag that I use, but I'm not sure how to write the `generate` function to do this.

Here is what I'm doing for my current function:

```
const markdownPaths = [
    'blog',
    'guest',
    'random'
];
function dynamicMarkdownRoutes() {
    return [].concat(
        ...markdownPaths.map(mdPath => {
            return glob.sync(`${mdPath}/*.md`, { cwd: 'content' })
            .map(filepath => `${mdPath}/${path.basename(filepath, '.md')}`);
        })
    );
}
export default {
    // a bunch of other stuff
    ....

    generate: {
        routes: dynamicMarkdownRoutes()
    },
}
```

...which works great to create the dynamic routes from the markdown files itself, but I can't work out how to extend this function to include routes from the front matter.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to read the front matter from Nuxt's `npm run generate` command, so instead I elected to use a gulp process to generate markdown files from the front matter instead. Now the `npm run generate` command can detect the newly created markdown files from the `content/tags` directory and create index files for them just like it would with my regular posts.

For reference, here's the gulp process:

```
const markdownToJSON  = require('gulp-markdown-to-json'),
      marked          = require('marked'),
      file            = require('gulp-file');

function meta(){
    return src('content/blog')
        .pipe(markdownToJSON(marked, function(d){
            if(d.tags){
                var tags = [];
                for(c in d.tags){
                    var e = d.tags[c].toLowerCase();
                    saveMD(e+'.md', 'content/tags');
                }
            }
        }));
}

function saveMD(src,destination){
    return file(src, '')
        .pipe(dest(destination));
}
```